# move option from one select to another select with JS

Tags: javascript, html

From two html selects, I would like to move when I click the button to move an option to another select with javascript vanila, and when it has been moved, it is removed from the select from where it was at the beginning. It should also work the other way around.

```js
function move1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("select1");
}

function move2() {}
```

```html
<select id="select1">
  <option value="0">1</option>
  <option value="0">2</option>
  <option value="0">3</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="move1()">&gt;&gt;</button>
<button type="button" onclick="move2()">&lt;&lt;</button>
<select id="select2"></select>
```

Comment: Okay well, show the code this is about and the solution you've tried to come up with. Then we'll take a look to see what we can do.

Comment: Is this for a homework assignment?

Comment: Yes, I want to practice with two select passing information.

Comment: I see. We can help you with that. What part of the assignment are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

- Fetch both selects with `getElementById()` and store them in `select_1` and `select_2` variables.
- Check if selected option exists by compering `selectedIndex` property of the select with `-1`. It will be equal to `-1` only if the user didn't select anything.
- If `selectedIndex` is equal to `-1`, then do nothing because there is nothing to transfer to second select.
- If `selectedIndex` is different from `-1`, it means that user selected something and option with that index should be transfered.
- Create new option for second select with `document.createElement('option')` and copy the selected option values to the new option.
- Remove the selected option of current select with `select.options.remove(select.selectedIndex)`

```js
function move1() {
  const select_1 = document.getElementById("select1");
  const select_2 = document.getElementById("select2");
  
  if(select_1.selectedIndex !== -1) {
    const selected_option = select_1.options[select_1.selectedIndex];
    
    let new_option = document.createElement('option');
    new_option.value = selected_option.value
    new_option.innerHTML = selected_option.innerHTML;
    select_2.appendChild(new_option);
    
    select_1.options.remove(select_1.selectedIndex)
  }

}

function move2(){
  const select_1 = document.getElementById("select1");
  const select_2 = document.getElementById("select2");
  
  if(select_2.selectedIndex !== -1) {
    const selected_option = select_2.options[select_2.selectedIndex];
    
    let new_option = document.createElement('option');
    new_option.value = selected_option.value
    new_option.innerHTML = selected_option.innerHTML;
    select_1.appendChild(new_option);
    
    select_2.options.remove(select_2.selectedIndex)
  }
  
}
```

```html
<select id="select1">
  <option value="0">1</option>
  <option value="0">2</option>
  <option value="0">3</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="move1()">&gt;&gt;</button>
<button type="button" onclick="move2()">&lt;&lt;</button>
<select id="select2"></select>
```

Comment: Be mindful that OP might still be learning and therefor might not understand all of your code. So be sure to be clear and describe what your solution does. For more guidance see [how do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: You are right. I added a description.

Comment: Thank you! the only thing that moves me all the elements, and I only want to move the selected option.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you try it now?

Comment: Work! thanks. What do innerHTML?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that can manage more than 2 sets of `<select>` and `<button>` pairs. If there are more than 2 pairs, all recieving `<select>` will add the selcted `<option>`. In the HTML a `data-*` attribute is added to each `<option>`:

```
<option data-idx="0" value='1'>1</option>
<option data-idx='1' value="2">2</option>
<option data-idx='2' value="3">3</option>
```

The value of `data-idx` is the `<option>`s original index position. In the event handler `switchOPt(e)` the `data-idx` value will be used to determine what index it should be placed in:

```
to.add(copy, +copy.dataset.idx);
```

***All details are commented in the example.***

```js
/* 
Collect all buttons into a HTMLCollection then convert it 
into an Array. Same with all select
*/
const btnArray = [...document.querySelectorAll('button')];
const selArray = [...document.querySelectorAll('select')];

/*
Iterate through the array of buttons. Register each button 
to the click event. The event handler is switchOpt(e)
*/
btnArray.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', switchOpt));

// Event handler always passes the Event Object
function switchOpt(e) {
  /*
  Determine the select that will send it's option by
  matching it's #id vs this.name (the [name] of the button 
  the user clicked
  */
  const from = document.getElementById(this.name);
  // if the select doesn't have any options end function
  if (from.childElementCount < 1) return;
  /*
  Determine the select that adds an option by .filter() 
  under the condition that it is NOT >from<
  */
  let to = selArray.filter(sel => sel.id != from.id);
  // Rereference >to< to be the select with the array
  to = to[0];
  // Determine which option has been selected
  const opt = from.options[from.selectedIndex];
  // Make a copy of the selected option
  const copy = opt.cloneNode(true);
  /*
  Add >copy< to >to< the second parameter is the index
  of the element that >copy< will be placed before it so 
  it'll always be in order
  */
  to.add(copy, +copy.dataset.idx);
  // Remove the option from >from<
  opt.remove();
}
```

```html
<!-- Assign each option a data attribute wuth the value
of it's index -->
<select id="A">
  <option data-idx='0' value="1">1</option>
  <option data-idx='1' value="2">2</option>
  <option data-idx='2' value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button name='A' type="button">&gt;&gt;</button>
<button name='B' type="button">&lt;&lt;</button>
<select id="B"></select>
```